# Do you think there's a market for maths games beyond simple arithmetic?

Tags: arithmetic

I recently created a game for android. I wanted to find out if there's actually someone who would play something like Pythagoras' theorem based game like this:

https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.rizn.pythagoras

I have some more ideas such as calculating unit of circle, some trigonometry, etc. (maybe not as dry as this one, maybe adding some more elements of fun and better graphics).

Just wondering if creating such games is waste of time or if actually someone would be interested in them.

Do you think that you can compel "general public" to maths problems beyond simple arithmetic? There are plenty of games which ask you to add or subtract numbers, but not that many which would involve a bit more difficult problems.

Thanks for answers.

Cheers,
Ryszard

Comment: Apologies for asking the wrong question at wrong forum. I thought I could get better feedback here, knowing here are quite a few maths geeks.

Comment: **Welcome to Math SE!** If you asking about how you can improve your game in terms of programming, perhaps [Stack Overflow](http://stackoverflow.com/) would be a better place to ask this. However, you should divert from asking our for our _opinions_. Best of luck on your game though :)

Comment: There are certainly people who would play mathematical games; have you seen http://euclidthegame.com for example? I don't know about the general public, nor about whether there's a "market" (if that means an opportunity to make money from it).

Comment: I think most people would think it's an educational product, as in for high school or GED students.